# UTL_MATCH Performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got 2 tables 1 with millions of records and the other with 200k. I'm attempting to do a UTL match with a couple of concatenated columns but of course this process would take a significant amount of time (comparing each record millions of times). The x.code is just another requirement for the comparison of table1
Is there any way that this could be sped up? It took 18min to compare 100 rows

```
select * 

from table1 x
where exists(select * 
             from largetable y 
             where x.state = y.state and 
                   utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(x.address || ' ' || x.city, y.address || ' ' || y.city) > 95 and 
                   x.code like '%a%'
            );
```

Comment: When I had to solve something similar, I used the premise that the first or last characters must match.  For larger tables, requiring the first or last n characters to be an exact match would still cut the search space to a reasonable size assuming an even distribution

Comment: Unfortunately I can't guarantee that my fields have any static characters that are the same among both tables

Comment: I suspect most of the performance issue is simply due to the need to scan a large number of blocks from `largetable`. I would consider adding a covering function-based index on `(y.state, y. address || ' ' || y.city)` which would reduce the number of blocks required to read through the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a distance match.  By that logic there must be some similarity between the fields that can be indexed.  Find some function which produces an indexable result, and use that for the search space for each row.

For example, you have a `City` field - most normalized city names are going to be an exact match (and you could normalize distinct values of city to a separate table to fix spelling errors).  Once you have a city match, you have likely reduced your search space for address by a fair bit.

If that is not enough, produce three "match" keys of first two alpha characters of first word of address, last two alpha characters of first word of address, numbers present in address.  Use the three "match" keys as a winnowing function prior to considering edit distance.

For example, in matching "123 Mulberry lane" to "123 Mlberry ln", the steps would be:

```
123 Mulberry Lane -> { numbers: '123', first: 'MU', last: 'RY' }
123 Mlberry Ln    -> { numbers: '123', first: 'ML', last: 'RY' }
```

So, while the first character winnow would cause the address to not be considered - the numbers and last heuristic still catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Distance matching produces a matrix of each row against every other row, so there's nothing which can be indexed. All you can do is reduce the set of records which need to be compared.

> Is there any way that this could be sped up?

Performance tuning is a bit of a science. Without more details on data skew and distribution  the more we can do is offer some guesses.

> The x.code is just another requirement for the comparison of table1

So, random guess: it might be a good idea to include that in the outer query.

```
select * 
from table1 x
where  x.code like '%a%'
and exists(select * 
             from largetable y 
             where x.state = y.state and 
                   utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(x.address || ' ' || x.city, y.address || ' ' || y.city) > 95                   
        );
```

Another random guess. Even if `largetable.state` is indexed it's probably not a very efficient access path, so maybe a (semi-) cross join might be more effective:

```
select distinct t1.* 
from table1 x
     join largetable y 
          on x.state = y.state 
where  x.code like '%a%'
and utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(x.address || ' ' || x.city, y.address || ' ' || y.city) > 95                   
;
```

---

This is why techniques like SOUNDEX() or Metaphone are handy: they provide approximations which can be used in equality operations, and which can be indexed. However, they are crude and are especially unforgiving of certain typos, so that's why we need other algorithms too. But maybe you can implement a multi-step approach, using a tokenizing approach to identify some matches and edit distance to winnow the remainder.